# Perl-Minimum & Maximum value

Tags: perl

input file

```
Xm_ABL1 Geneious    extracted region    1   168 .   +   .   Name=Extracted region from gi|371443098|gb|JH556762.1|;Extracted interval="3512970000000 -> 3514640000000"
Xm_ABL1 Geneious    extracted region    169 334 .   +   .   Name=Extracted region from gi|371443098|gb|JH556762.1|;Extracted interval="3717850000000 -> 3719500000000"
```

part of perl code

```
 if ($array[1] =~ /extracted region/){
            die "No CDS record for $key!\n" unless $metadata->{$key};
    (my $label = $array[7]) =~ s/.*region from (.*)\|;.*/$1/;
    $label =~ s/\|/_/g;
    $group->{$label} ||= { 
            pos1 => 1e10,
            pos2 => 0,
            metadata => $metadata->{$key},
            sequences => [],
    };
    (my $pos1, my $arr, my $pos2) = ($array[7]=~/.*interval=\"(\d+) (<?->?) (\d+)\"$/gm);
    # capture hi/lo values for group
    $group->{$label}->{pos1} = $pos1 if $pos1 < $group->{$label}->{pos1};
    $group->{$label}->{pos2} = $pos2 if $pos2 > $group->{$label}->{pos2};
    # push this sequence onto the group's array
    push(@{ $group->{$label}->{sequences} }, [ $pos1, $pos2, $arrow->{$arr} ]);
}
```

In the code $pos1=3512970000000,3717850000000 & $pos2=3514640000000,3719500000000. My code prints new line finding minimum and maximum value (if $pos1 is less than 10,000), but if the value is greater than 10,0000 it gives error in printing minimum value of pos1. Any  help is appreciated in debugging for finding minimum value of $pos1 and maximum value of $pos2

Comment: this is a programming question: shouldn't it be on stackoverflow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$group->{$label}->{pos1}` is always defined, you inizialized it with line 6:

```
pos1 => 1e10,
```

so that, it work right until `$pos1 <= 1e10`.
If you want print minimum value `$group->{$label}->{pos1} = 3512970000000` (like your sample input), you must inizialize `$group->{$label}->{pos1} = -1` (line 6):

```
pos1 => -1,
```

and modify line 13 with:

```
$group->{$label}->{pos1} = $pos1 if (($group->{$label}->{pos1} < 0) || ($pos1 < $group->{$label}->{pos1}));
```

Answer (score 0):

by changing code at Line 13: using defiend

```
 $group->{$label}->{pos1} = $pos1 if ((!defined $group->{$label}->{pos1})
 ||  ($pos1 < $group->{$label}->{pos1}));
```